# Phonegap: SoftKeyboard does not work in Android 4.4

Tags: android, cordova

I have used the phonegap plugin SoftKeyboard  to control the display of Keyboard.
It works well in the previous Android version: 4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3.
However, after updating my device to 4.4, I found the keyboard could not be shown with the code:

```
SoftKeyboard.show();
```

I am not sure whether the reason is that Android changes its core engine to Chrome.

Any suggestion to let me know how to pop up the Keyboard will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your plugin git and your cordova version?

Comment: cordova 3.3 and the SoftKeyboard plugin

Comment: i am facing some strange issue. it works only on 4.4.2 and not on 4.1 4.2 4.3

Comment: @DeepMehta I am not sure why but I found the plugin only works well in cordova 3.0 so far.

Comment: @jack : i am using cordova 3.4 and its working for kitkat os. Rest JB ICS gingerbread its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin has been updated and it is working now. :)